# Vaadin. What to do when UI is not attached?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have the following situation. In my app i update some controls values periodically using Java's TimerTask.
The updation method looks like this:

```
public void updateDates()
{
   if(!myUI.get().isAttached())
       return;

    myUI.get().access(() -> {
        isAsyncUpdate = true;
        resetUnmodified();
        isAsyncUpdate = false;
        myUI.get().push();
    });
}
```

Ok, once the user logs in everything is being updated w/o any problems. Assume that user logs out and then the same user logs in. And after that the isAttached() method return false.
I can't understand why this happens and how to overcome this(
How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Is your myUI value valid, or updated with the new UI?

Comment: André, what do you mean? myUI.get() doesn't return null in this case.. but session is null in such situation

Comment: What do you do on logout ? Does the new user get a new VaadinUI object?

Comment: André, user was the same and each time it was logged in it received the same myUI. Controls the runnable updates are new each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems i found the roots of the issue. I used a single timer object to handle all the controls. Now i have refactored class to make it use its own timer per control. It seems it resolves the issue. But this solution is not perfect as for me: a single timer is better that many and the work they do it the same actually. But so far i don't know how to resolve this issue in some another way..

Answer (score -1):

You shoud use static method UI.getCurrent() and then cast it to your own myUI so you will be sure to get current used UI that is surely attached.

Comment: fante76, i already call UI.getCurrent() using the static get() method as I show in the code snippet above. Casting is made there too.

Comment: UI.getCurrent() does not work with background tasks (Which of the UI should be accessed?) You have to get hold of the UI in the foreground thread, and then pass that UI instance/value to all other threads

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that environment was a background task. If this task is started from GUI environment, this solution can be used, as you said, by passing UI to the task.